# Trying to install rdpdesk-3.0

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I believe I have installed all the prerequisites that the manual listed...For Building under Linux:

```
Download RDPDesk source
g++
autotools-dev
libxt-dev (>=1.0.6-0)
libgtk2.0 (>= 2.18.0)
libglib2.0 (>=2.22.0-0)
x11proto-core
libwxbase2.8 (>= 2.8.9)
libwxgtk2.8 (>= 2.8.9)
libssl-dev
```

I then ran these commands in the location where I unpacked the RDPDesk files

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
```

I believe these go through fine, but If you want me to post the results, I can.  Last, but not least, I ran these commands

```
make
sudo make install
```

but it errors out.  Result below...

```
rdpdesk-FRDPOptionsDialog.o rdpdesk-  FRDPKeyboard.o rdpdesk-autoupdate.o rdpdesk-CatcherWindowID.o -pthread -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z -Wl,relro  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lwx_gtk2u_richtext-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_aui-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_xrc-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_qa-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_html-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_adv-2.8 -lwx_gtk2u_core-2.8 -lwx_baseu_xml-2.8 -lwx_baseu_net-2.8 -lwx_baseu-2.8 -lglib-2.0 -lssl -lcrypto -lXaw -lz -ljpeg -pthread
/usr/bin/ld: rdpdesk-RDPConnection_nix.o: undefined reference to symbol 'gtk_widget_reparent'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [rdpdesk] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/fmccrary/Downloads/rdpdesk-3.2/src'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/fmccrary/Downloads/rdpdesk-3.2/src'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fmccrary/Downloads/rdpdesk-3.2/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`gtk_widget_reparent` is part of the GtkWidget class. If you're missing that, you're missing some GTK *development* files. Their packages tend to have a `-dev` tag on the end. You probably just need:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

Comment: I believe I installed this package already, but I ran the command again to verify.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.